# Maintaining a list of Panels containing controls. Losing Event Handlers

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, event-handling

I have two buttons at the top of my page Add Control and Clear Controls.

Clicking Add control fires off a function that creates a new Panel and a new DropDownList.

I assign the DropDownList an Eventhandler for SelectedIndexChanged.

The idea is that depending on the selection in my DropDownList, I will create another control within that panel.

Eventually the panel will contain some fields that I can pass off as parameters for my query.

I store the panels in a list of panels that gets recreated every postback.

The problem I have is I can Add the panels, remove the panels and clear all panels from my list but I CANNOT seem to be able to ever get the SelectedIndexChanged trigger to fire... it never seems to get assigned or it is lost on each Postback.

I have exhausted my googling expertise and I am getting quite frustrated with myself. I am open to suggestions/fixes.

Thank You.

```
List<Panel> persistControls = new List<Panel>();

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["persistControls"] != null)
    {
        persistControls = (List<Panel>)Session["persistControls"];
        int count = 0;

        foreach (Panel dynamicControl in persistControls)
        {
            AddQuestionTypeDropDownList(count);
            dynamicControl.ID = "panel" + count;

            Button btnRemove = new Button();
            btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
            btnRemove.Text = "Remove";
            btnRemove.CommandArgument = count.ToString();

            // Pushing to Placeholder
            myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(dynamicControl);
            myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(btnRemove);
            count++;
        }
    }
    base.OnInit(e);
}

// Calls three functions responsible for pulling from the Database and binding the Datagrid.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetClustersFromDatabase(userid);
        BindGrid();
        BindState();            
    }
}

private DropDownList AddQuestionTypeDropDownList(int count)
{
    DropDownList list = new DropDownList();

    list.ID = "list" + count;    
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select One--", ""));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Title", "1"));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Contact", "2"));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Date Created", "3"));
    list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
    list.AutoPostBack = true;

    return list;
}

private DropDownList AddQuestionTypeDropDownList()
{
    DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select One--", ""));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Title", "1"));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Contact", "2"));
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem("Date Created", "3"));
    list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
    list.AutoPostBack = true;

    return list;
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Panel panelContainer = new Panel();
        panelContainer.ID = "panel" + persistControls.Count;

        panelContainer.Controls.Add(AddQuestionTypeDropDownList());

        Button btnRemove = new Button();
        btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
        btnRemove.Text = "Remove";
        btnRemove.CommandArgument = persistControls.Count.ToString();

        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(panelContainer); // Pushes the Panel to the page.
        persistControls.Add(panelContainer);// Adds our Panel to the Control list

        myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(btnRemove); // Pushes our Button to the page.
        Session["persistControls"] = persistControls; // put it in the session
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I have no code here but thats because I currently can't even get it to fire.
    try
    {

    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session["persistControls"] = null;
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int deleteThisOne = int.Parse(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
        persistControls.Remove(persistControls[deleteThisOne]);
        Session["persistControls"] = persistControls;          
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add events to controls in the Page_Load. Events registered in OnInit will never fire...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by iterating through my list of panels with a foreach and having a nested foreach to iterate through each control in that panel. I check the type of control and fix the eventhandler on every postback.